# Spring boot 2 migration: missing sequence

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, flyway

I had spring boot 1.5.16 and now migrating to 2.3.8.RELEASE.

I have an entity with a generated ID field.
Now as I have probably newer dependencies, there is the following error from flyway:

> Schema-validation: missing sequence [id_or_generated]

Which comes from the entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "IdOrGenerated")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "IdOrGenerated", strategy = "<path>.MyEntityUseIdOrGenerate")
    private Long id;
}
```

```
public class MyEntityUseIdOrGenerate extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {

        if (obj == null)
            throw new HibernateException(new NullPointerException());

        if ((((MyEntity) obj).getId()) == null) {

            return super.generate(session, obj);
        }

        return ((MyEntity) obj).getId();
    }

}
```

Does anyone have an idea, why it's not working anymore with a newer hibernate version?
And what I have to do? Do I have to create the sequence in my postgres DB?

Comment: check the documentation ```(Optional) The name of the primary key generator to use as specified in the SequenceGenerator or TableGenerator annotation.
Defaults to the id generator supplied by persistence provider.```

Comment: On what Flyway version did you run with 1.5 and what Flyway version do use with 2.3 ?

Comment: There was a change in Hibernate 5.x regarding the generator mappings if I remember correctly. But sure, the validation error tells you to generate that sequence. Before the upgrade: Where did you get the next ID from?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe It was flyway-core:4.2.0 and not it is flyway-core:6.4.4.

Comment: @DanielWosch Good question, I guess from the generation of the MyEntityUseIdOrGenerate

Comment: @Galadriel you need to know that you cannot directly upgrade Flyway from 4.x to 6.x. You need to do a release with Flyway 5.x in between. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#flyway for more info.